# Errow while pushing to Arch User Repository

Tags: git, hook, archlinux

I want to publish my command line utility on arch linux user repository. I have ran the command `makepkg --printsrcinfo > .SRCINFO` and added `PKGBUILD` file and `.SRCINFO` file with git.

Bellow error appeared after pushed with git.

```
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.08 KiB | 368.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "hooks/update", line 11, in <module>
remote:     load_entry_point('aurweb==4.8.0', 'console_scripts', 'aurweb-git-update')()
remote:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aurweb-4.8.0-py3.8.egg/aurweb/git/update.py", line 306, in main
remote: KeyError: 'pkgbase'
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To ssh://aur.archlinux.org/myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens on the remote side. Also, the error report doesn't look like a normal preconditions checking failure, it looks more like an internal bug.

So the only thing you can do with the error is to report it to the Arch repository maintainers and ask them to help you with resolving the issue.

Comment: At the remote site there is a hook `hooks/update` written in Python and it failed with the traceback. Either the hook is buggy or it expected some condition that was not met (or perhaps both because the problem should be reported back to the user as an error message, not a traceback).

Comment: I have contacted an AUR maintainer. After that he told me to remove existing `.git` folder and initialize a new git repo. After it worked.

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi did he clarify why the error happened?